# SQL Query to identify "Top Performers" [?]

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I'm still learning Oracle SQL and would like your guidance.

Let say, we have MONTHLY_SALES_TOTALS table that has 3 fields: `name`, `region`, `amount`.  We need to determine the best sales people per region.  Best means that their amount is equal to the maximum for the region.

```
CREATE TABLE montly_sales_totals
(
 name varchar(20), 
 amount numeric(9), 
 region varchar(30)
);

INSERT ALL
 INTO montly_sales_totals (name, amount, region) VALUES ('Peter', 55555,  'east')
 INTO montly_sales_totals (name, amount, region) VALUES ('Susan', 55555, 'east')
 INTO montly_sales_totals (name, amount, region) VALUES ('Mark', 1000000, 'south')
 INTO montly_sales_totals (name, amount, region) VALUES ('Glenn', 50000, 'east')
 INTO montly_sales_totals (name, amount, region) VALUES ('Paul', 500000, 'south')
SELECT * from dual;
```

Possible solution:

```
SELECT m1.name, m1.region, m1.amount 
FROM montly_sales_totals m1
JOIN 
 (SELECT MAX(amount) max_amount, region FROM montly_sales_totals GROUP BY region) m2
 ON (m1.region = m2.region)
WHERE m1.amount = m2.max_amount
ORDER by 2,1;
```

*SQL Fiddle*: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/6a2d8/6

Now my questions:

1. How efficient is such query?
2. How can/should it be simplified and/or improved?
3. I could not use **Top** since the number of "max" rows vary by region.  Is it another direct functionality I could've used instead?

Answer (score 5):

I would use RANK():

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
   SELECT name, amount, region,
       RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY region ORDER BY amount DESC) rnk
   FROM montly_sales_totals
  ) t
WHERE t.rnk = 1
```

Here's a modified version of the [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/6a2d8/8)

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of ways one can go about this. Here's another:

```
       select S.region, S.name, V.regionmax
       from sales as S
       inner join
       (
        select region, max(amount) as regionmax
       from sales group by region 
       ) as V
       on S.region = V.region and S.amount = regionmax
```

As to efficiency, the main factor is the use of the proper index(es).  Inline views can perform very well.

Answer (score 1):

I like CTE syntax, but using that website the time taken is the same 2ms, so I can't beat yours :)

```
with Maximums as (
  SELECT region,
    MAX(amount) max_amount
  FROM montly_sales_totals GROUP BY region
)
SELECT m1.name, m1.region, m1.amount 
FROM montly_sales_totals m1, Maximums 
WHERE (m1.amount = Maximums.max_amount)
  and (m1.region = Maximums.region)
ORDER by 2,1;
```

Comment: But in the where-clause you need to include the region too.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this by using the function too...

```
select * from (select m1.*, row_number( ) over (partition by m1.region order by m1.amount desc,m1.name  desc ) max_sal from montly_sales_totals m1 ) where max_sal =1 ;
```

this query can do one extra thing if both employee sal are same!

Comment: Each region can have **multiple** best performers.

Comment: oh...u mean u need the candidate names....who have amount equal to max amount right!?

Comment: Yes. This is how it's spelled out in my original post.